# VB Code working only in the first row, please advice

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
Dim score As Integer, result As String
score = Range("G1")


    If score = 101 Then result = "3565"
    If score = 120 Then result = "4689"
    If score = 103 Then result = "3560"
    If score = 104 Then result = "3567"
    If score = 105 Then result = "3568"
    If score = 106 Then result = "3564"
    If score = 110 Then result = "3679"
    If score = 118 Then result = "4235"
    If score = 119 Then result = "4341"

Range("A1") = result

End Sub
```

Comment: If you want to work on multiple rows, use a loop (but this is a great time to use a lookup table).

Comment: You really ought to consider just executing a SQL query to update the rows within VBA code. That will really simplify the solution.

Answer (score 1):

This could be one approach:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro1()

Dim score As Long, result As String
Dim lrow As Long
Dim i As Long


Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Set the name of your sheet


lrow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row 'Find last row in Sheet1, column G


For i = 1 To lrow

score = ws.Cells(i, "G").Value

Select Case score
    Case Is = 101
        result = "3565"
    Case Is = 120
        result = "4689"
    Case Is = 103
        result = "3560"
    Case Is = 104
        result = "3567"
    Case Is = 105
        result = "3568"
    Case Is = 106
        result = "3564"
    Case Is = 110
        result = "3679"
    Case Is = 118
        result = "4235"
    Case Is = 119
        result = "4341"
End Select

ws.Cells(i, "A").Value = result

Next i


End Sub
```

---

Alternative could be:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro2()

Dim score As Long, result As String
Dim lrow As Long
Dim i As Long


Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Set the name of your sheet


lrow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row 'Find last row in Sheet1


For i = 1 To lrow

score = ws.Cells(i, "G").Value

    If score = 101 Then result = "3565"
    If score = 120 Then result = "4689"
    If score = 103 Then result = "3560"
    If score = 104 Then result = "3567"
    If score = 105 Then result = "3568"
    If score = 106 Then result = "3564"
    If score = 110 Then result = "3679"
    If score = 118 Then result = "4235"
    If score = 119 Then result = "4341"

ws.Cells(i, "A").Value = result

Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: Thank You. You are awesome.

Comment: Glad it helped. Let me know if you have any questions. Happy coding :)!